# Check if it's possible to sort permutation using given operation

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have the following problem:
My task is to determine if it's possible to sort given permutation, but using only one type of operation: we can move i-th element two positions to the left. Equally elements i-1 and i-2 move one position to the right.

For example:
It's possible to sort permutation (2,5,3,4,1), but we can't do that with permutation (2,3,5,4,1).

(2,5,3,**4**,1)
(2,4,5,**3**,1)
(2,3,4,5,**1**)
(2,3,**1**,4,5)
(1,2,3,4,5)

Complexity should be probably linear.
I came up with quadratic solution, but it's too slow. I tried greedy approach, but it failed.

This problem has me completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to sort a permutation using only this operation iff there is an even number of inversions. You can count inversions using merge sort in O(n log n).